# Testing a Textbox value failure

Tags: testing, textbox, conditional-statements

So here goes   (VBA Word): I'm picking a specific Text Box and testing to see if it's contents are equal to a specific string.   All of this works - except I always get a false response.  When I post the value in Debug.print is shows "Something Important"  which should have been a true response.  triggering a change in the text.   Never does.

(VBA Word macro follows:)

```
     Sub testit()

        Dim WD as document
        Dim StringOne as string

        set WD = Application.ActiveDocument

        StringOne = "Something Important"
            'this line will always come back false    -  why?*
        If WD.Shapes.Range("Text Box 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = stringOne Then
                WD.Shapes.Range("Text Box 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Something More"
        Else
        ' This will say "Something Important"
                Debug.Print WD.Shapes.Range("Text Box 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        '  And Just in case I typed something wrong let's enter it again into the textbox 
                WD.Shapes.Range("Text Box 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Something Important"
        End If

     End Sub
```

This is a simplification of a more complex program.   I will be tests several Text Boxes, Which I will call by name and change accordingly in the WORD document for presentation reasons.  IE:  Change the .fontsize, .bold. etc.  Accordingly.   Some textboxes will have different settings according to the layout of the WORD doc.    Regardless, if I can't test the value of the text in a textbox...  it will never change.

Comment: Oh it doesn't matter what shape I choose.   Textbox, Rectangle, Oval, WordArt, Autoshape , etc....  I can change the text value...  but I can never test it.   If conditional will alway return false.

Comment: So I thought I could do a StrComp (a string comparison)  Now it always comes up true.  Even when the text in the shape does not match.
'''  If StrComp(WD.Shapes.Range("Text Box 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text, stringOne) then '''

Comment: It must be something about expression.Shapes.Range(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text can only accept values.   Still digging....

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, it is a character mapping problem.

```
If WD.Shapes.Range("Text Box 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = stringOne then
```

needs to be corrected as a length issue

```
If Left(Wd.Shapes.Range(ShapeName).TextFrame.TextRange.Text, Len(StringOne)) = StringOne Then
```

There seems to be a few blank or formatting characters that the graphic needs at the end of the string which you can trim off.